# Count all different record relation with single MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table `subArticles`, which includes sub articles and has a column named `_topRecord` inside, which holds a number to specify the top article.

Also,each **article** can have many **sub-articles**, so the `subArticles` table may have several records where `_topRecord = 10`.

Now I want to count how many **subArticles** every **article** owns. I can do it this way when I know the specific **Article ID**:

```
SELECT Count(*) 
  FROM subArticles 
 WHERE _topRecord = 2;
```

But for 80 articles I don't want to replay this query for 80 times.

How can it be done in an SQL Query solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*),_topRecord 
    FROM subArticles 
GROUP BY _topRecord?
```